# Nested Function Composition

Tags: functional-programming, lambda-calculus

I am unable to wrap my head around the following function composition:

```
function plus_one(x) {
    return x + 1;
}

function trans(f) {
    return function(x) {
        return 2 * f(2 * x);
    };
}

function twice(f) {
    return function(x) {
        return f(f(x));
    }
}
```

When I attempt to evaluate `((twice)(trans))(plus_one)(1)`
This is what I get, assuming `plus_one` is f

```
f(2f(2x))=2f(2*2f(2x))=2f(4f(2x)) = 2*(4*(2 + 1)) = 24.
```

But typing it into the interpreter reveals that it is 20.

Comment: why the `lambda-calculus` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`((twice)(trans))(plus_one)` is `trans(trans(plus_one))`, and

```
trans(trans(plus_one)) (1)
—> trans(λx.2 * plus_one(2*x)) (1)
—> λy.2 * ((λx.2 * plus_one(2*x))(2*y) (1)
—> 2 * (λx.2 * plus_one(2*x)) (2*1)
-> 2 * 2 * plus_one(2*2)
-> 2 * 2 * 5
-> 20
```

Answer (score 1):

It might help to use different parameter names in the different function for not confusing them. `f` does not always refer to `plus_one`.

With

```
plus_one = λ x0 ⇒ x0 + 1;
trans = λ f0 ⇒ λ x1 ⇒ 2 * f0(2 * x1);
twice = λ f1 ⇒ λ x2 ⇒ f1(f1(x2));
```

we can evaluate

```
twice(trans)(plus_one)(1)
```

as

```
≡ (λ f1 ⇒ λ x2 ⇒ f1(f1(x2)))(trans)(plus_one)(1)
≡ (λ x2 ⇒ trans(trans(x2)))(plus_one)(1)
≡ trans(trans(plus_one)))(1)
≡ (λ f0 ⇒ λ x1 ⇒ 2 * f0(2 * x1))(trans(plus_one)))(1)
≡ (λ x1 ⇒ 2 * trans(plus_one)(2 * x1))(1)
≡ 2 * trans(plus_one)(2 * 1)
≡ 2 * (λ f0 ⇒ λ x1 ⇒ 2 * f0(2 * x1))(plus_one)(2 * 1)
≡ 2 * (λ x1 ⇒ 2 * plus_one(2 * x1))(2 * 1)
≡ 2 * 2 * plus_one(2 * (2 * 1))
≡ 2 * 2 * (λ x0 ⇒ x0 + 1)(2 * (2 * 1))
≡ 2 * 2 * ((2 * (2 * 1)) + 1)
≡ 20
```

Answer (score 0):

Notation is everything.

```
plus_one(x) = (x + 1)
trans(f)(x) = 2 * f(2 * x)
twice(f)(x) = f(f(x))

twice(trans)(plus_one)(1)
=
trans(trans(plus_one))(1)
=
2 * (trans(plus_one))(2 * 1)
=
2 * trans(plus_one)(2)
=
2 * (2 * plus_one(2 * 2))
=
2 * (2 * (4 + 1))
=
20
```

See also:

- [Combinatory Logic (Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-combinatory/)
- [Combinatory logic - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic)
- [Rewriting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewriting)